How do I solve for a variable for a derivative equation?
So I'm entering this as input:
f[p_] := Subscript[l, i] Log[ p] + (N - Subscript[l, i]) Log[1 - p]
f'[p]

Solve[Sum[f'[p], {i, 1, n}] == 0, p]

However, get an error that Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. How do I fix this?

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Is your N suppose to represent the same variable as the lower case n, or are these two different?

I don't know whether Mathematica can solve this in general form, but you can guess the solution by solving the equation at different $n$:
f[p_] := Subscript[l, i] Log[p] + (n - Subscript[l, i]) Log[1 - p];

Table[SolveValues[Sum[f'[p], {i, 1, n}] == 0, p], {n, 1, 10}] // Column


So you can assume a general form of solution:
$$p = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i.$$

Sorry for making an off-topic comment here but I want to get your attention. You have support from other members to become a moderator if you nominate yourself in the ongoing election. Please consider it!

Expanding on my comments from reddit
If your N is supposed to be the same as the upper sum bound n:
f[p_] := l[i] Log[p] + (n - l[i]) Log[1 - p]
summand = f'[p];

Split up the summand by powers of l[i]
maxLPower = Exponent[summand, l[i]];
sumPowers = Table[Sum[l[i]^p, {i, n}], {p, 0, 1}];
lCoeffs = CoefficientList[summand, l[i]];

eq = lCoeffs . sumPowers == 0 // Together;

yielding

$$
\frac{n^2 p-\sum _i^n l(i)}{(p-1) p}=0
$$

Which if assume $p \neq 0 \land p \neq 1$, has solution
$$
p=\frac{\sum _i^n l(i)}{n^2}
$$
Solve is also able to handle this
Solve[eq, p]


p -> Sum[l[i], {i, n}]/n^2


If N $\neq$ n, then it's pretty similar
f[p_] := l[i] Log[p] + (bigN - l[i]) Log[1 - p]
summand = f'[p];

maxLPower = Exponent[summand, l[i]];
sumPowers = Table[Sum[l[i]^p, {i, n}], {p, 0, 1}];
lCoeffs = CoefficientList[summand, l[i]];

eq = lCoeffs . sumPowers == 0 // Together


$$ 
\frac{\text{bigN} ~n ~p-\sum _i^n l(i)}{(p-1) p}=0
$$

Which if again assume $p \neq 0 \land p \neq 1$, has solution
$$
p=\frac{\sum _i^n l(i)}{\text{bigN} ~n}
$$
Solve[eq,p]


p -> Sum[l[i], {i, n}]/(bigN*n)

